# Let $f$ be an odd meromorphic function , what can I deduce about $res (f,0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f$ be an odd meromorphic function. What can I deduce about $res(f,0)$?

Comment: Just off the bat I'd say "nothing", since $z$ and $1/z$ both are odd and meromorphic. I might be missing something, though.

Comment: Nothing. $f(z) = \frac cz$ is odd and meromorphic, it's residue in $0$ is $c$.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't deduce anything, as $f(z) = \frac cz$ is odd and in $0$ its residue is $c$, which is an arbitrary complex number

Comment: can anyone please justify this in a more formal form? I am quite comfused

Comment: @Mike Confused about what? You know that the residue is a complex number. Now you say "Okay, in general for an arbitrary function is a complex number. But what about odd functions? Do they have some properties I can use to show something about the residue? " And the answer is no, because, as my example show, even if a function is odd the residue can be any complex number, so really you have no more information. Anyhow tell what you're confused about and we'll try to help you! :-)